# Prefix changed from ct100_ to ct100$

Tags: asp.net

I have recently migrated a website from one server to another. The websites have been setup correctly on IIS and are able to connect. However, I am facing an issue with the prefixes that are added by .net for the asp.net controls. The asp.net controls (like a textbox) automatically prefixes ct100_ with the name of the control. This was working fine as I referenced ct100_nameofthecontrol in the javascript. But now the prefix have been changed to ct100$ instead of ct100_

For example

I have an asp.net control textbox with name **txtSearchName** on a page. When the page gets rendered the name of the textbox was changed from **txtSearchName** to **ctl00_bodyContent_txtSearchName**  but after the migration, the same name is being changed to **ctl00$bodyContent$txtSearchName**.

[image: new server naming]

Is there a way or a configuration to change the _ with $ or I have to change the references to javascript code?

[image]

please help

Thanks

**Updated Solution:**

The code should have the ClientIDMode set to static for the controls. However, the application was already built by the developers and this bug was raised when the server was changed.It was a tiresome task to do if I needed to change the code and it could have easily broken the code at a point. The _ and $ signs are dependent upon the CLR version. I changed the CLR version from V4.0 to V2.0 in the application pool on IIS manager and everything was working again.

Comment: you can try `ClientIDMode="Static"` with your control. This will guarantee what ever name with id you will give it will not change it.

Comment: You should get the client side ID from ASP.NET and not rely on any other behavior. That way it will always work. Now everything will easily break with just a little change in structure. Or use static names like Afnan mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You should not hard-code the ID's in JavaScript. And you could indeed use `ClientIDMode="Static"`, but that is not recommended since it could lead to duplicate ID's. Better use `ClientID`

```
$("#<%= txtSearchName.ClientID %>").val('');
$("#<%= txtSearchName.ClientID %>").focus();
```